# Position icon / images inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I´m starting my web developer training and i´m having trouble to move (in this case center) icons / images and text inside flexboxes.
Can anyone help?
 my html

```
<div class="thirdcontainer">
    <span class="flex3">
        <img src="../challenge/img/feature-quality.png"> 
   <img src="../challenge/img/feature-reliability.png"> 
    <img src="../challenge/img/feature-speed.png"> </span>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.thirdcontainer{
width: 1200px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #173493;
margin: 0 auto;
color: white;
font-family: open sans, serif;
font-size: 12px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

```
.thirdcontainer{
width: 1200px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #173493;
margin: 0 auto;
color: white;
font-family: open sans, serif;
font-size: 12px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `display: flex;` to the containers CSS...

(note: I changed `width` to `max-width` for this example to make it fit in the snippet window).

```css
.thirdcontainer{
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #173493;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: open sans, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="thirdcontainer">
  <span class="flex3">
        <img src="../challenge/img/feature-quality.png"> 
   <img src="../challenge/img/feature-reliability.png"> 
    <img src="../challenge/img/feature-speed.png"> </span>
</div>
```